# how to change the download directory/location in pipe() method?

Tags: javascript, node.js

this code downloads the files in the project folders, how do i change this to another location?

```
await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let fileExt = post.url.split(".").pop();
    request(`${post.url}`)
      .pipe(
        fs.createWriteStream(
          `${post.title.slice(0, 10).replace(/ +/g, "")}.${fileExt}`
        )
      )
      .on("finish", () => {
        console.log("download success..!");
        resolve();
      })
      .on("error", (error) => {
        console.log("from event ===>", error);
        rejects(error);
      });
  });
```

Comment: Put the directory in front of the filename.. `/somedir/${post....`. Ps.  You probably want to tag this question node too.

Comment: https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/advanced/streams/how-to-use-fs-create-write-stream/ might be of help?